# Process comma separated input and check format

Tags: c++, performance, csv

I have to read console input and store data in the vector of structs. In case of any data format violation I have to print `"Malformed Input"` and return `1`

Data format:

1 The first line is `"#job_id,runtime_in_seconds,next_job_id"`

2 The next lines are three comma separated integers (number of lines can be different)

Example:

```
#job_id,runtime_in_seconds,next_job_id
1,60,23
2,23,3
3,12,0
23,30,0
```

Could you please advise how to write better code in terms of time performance?

I was thinking about `scanf("%d,%d,%d", &arg1, &arg2, &arg3)` but not sure that it's C++ style

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;


struct Job {
    int job_id;
    int runtime;
    int next_job_id;
};


std::optional<Job> make_job(const string& s) {
    int job_id = 0, runtime = 0, next_job_id = 0;
    int i = 0;
    
    while (i < s.size() and s[i] >= '0' and s[i] <= '9') {
        job_id = job_id * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
        ++i;
    }
    if (i == s.size() or s[i] != ',') {
        return nullopt;
    }
    ++i;
    
    while (i < s.size() and s[i] >= '0' and s[i] <= '9') {
        runtime = runtime * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
        ++i;
    }
    if (i == s.size() or s[i] != ',') {
        return nullopt;
    }
    ++i;
    
    while (i < s.size() and s[i] >= '0' and s[i] <= '9') {
        next_job_id = next_job_id * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
        ++i;
    }
    if (i != s.size()) {
        return nullopt;
    }
    return Job {job_id, runtime, next_job_id};
}


int main() {
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    if (line.compare("#job_id,runtime_in_seconds,next_job_id")) {
        cout << "Malformed Input";
        return 1;
    }

    vector<Job> jobs;
    while (getline(cin, line)) {
        const auto job = make_job(line);
        if (not job) {
            cout << "Malformed Input";
            return 1;
        }
        jobs.push_back(*job);
    }
    // process Jobs
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite complex. A much simpler way would be to use the stream functionality:

```
std::optional<Job> make_job(std::stringstream s) {
    Job job;

    s >> job.job_id;
    if (s.get() != ',')
        return std::nullopt;

    s >> job.runtime;
    if (s.get() != ',')
        return std::nullopt;

    s >> job.next_job_id;
    // check that we have reached the end without any errors
    if (!s.eof() || !s)
        return std::nullopt;

    return job;
}
```

This might involve a copy of the string into the stringstream, but since C++23 `std::stringstream` you can move `std::string`s into it, or you could use `std::spanstream`. Alternatively, you could just pass the input stream directly to `make_job()`:

```
std::optional<Job> make_job(std::istream& s) {
    …
    // check that we have reached the end of the line without any errors
    if (s.get() != '\n' || !s)
        return std::nullopt;
    …
}
```

Although reading the file explictly line-by-line is probably a good thing to do.

If reading a malformed job would be an exceptional event, consider just throwing an exception instead of using `std::optional`. This will simplify the code:

```
Job make_job(std::stringstream s) {
    …
    // check that we have reached the end of the line without any errors
    if (!s.eof() || !s)
        throw std::runtime_error("Malformed input");
    …
}

int main() {
    …
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        jobs.push_back(make_job(line));
    }
    …
}
```

Also ensure you check that you have encountered the end of the file after the `while`-loop finished; `std::getline()` returns `false` also in case of errors, and you don't want to ignore those. So:

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    …
}

if (!std::cin.eof()) {
    std::cerr << "Error reading input\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```